# Security Issues with custom user role or changing core role capabilities?

Tags: customization, user-roles

I have a scenario where I need a editor like role but with extended capabilities where they can access woocommerce orders,products and user page. If I would to create a custom role or change the core editor role with these extended capabilities, will there be any security issue in the site or will there be a code break in the site when i'm upgrading wordpress version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying the editor role by adding new capabilities will grant users editor capabilities plus these new capabilities. As long as you're comfortable with that level of access, there aren't additional security concerns.

If you want to create a new role which is what I recommend for this scenario, you can craft the capabilities according to your needs and only grant the capabilities you want these users to have.

The only concerns I would have with updates is if the core WordPress editor role were to change in the future.

Comment: Hi Mike, if i were to create a new role for this scenario. Will there be a clash for the updates with the core Wordpress?

Comment: There won't be any conflicts as long as you don't use the names of one of the pre-defined roles. Check out `add_role` https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role

Comment: Great!!! thanks alot mike!!!!

Answer (score -1):

You can use Advanced Access Manager Plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-access-manager/ works user level based capabilities  from wp-admin dashboard it's works woocommerce also.

Comment: Hi Ravi, thanks for the suggestion.But this is not the answer i'm looking for, but I will keep in mind for this role editor plugin if I happen to need it down the road =)